# Warning: Division by zero and Notice: Undefined variable: Heightn in for Display image in php

Tags: php

I am a beginner. Please advise.

1. The following code shows two errors despite displaying pictures :

   upper table:

   > Warning: Division by zero in C:\xampp\htdocs\testpic\1.php on line 22

   upper each pic:

   > Notice: Undefined variable: Heightn in C:\xampp\htdocs\testpic\1.php on line 26
2. Patterns are named after the pattern (customer number_order number_etc.). I would like to have each group of pictures containing the same (`customer_numbered` order) separate from the others with the same headline.

   Example :

   - 7700251_350_1621_...
   - 7700251_350_2030_...
   - And ....

   In a table titled `7700251_350` and separated from photos by number

   - 7700252_352_2030_...
   - 7700252_352_4030_...
   - And ....

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <table align="left" border="1" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
    <?php
    $files = glob("pic/*.*");
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($files); $i=$i+3) {
    echo "<tr>";
    for ($j=0;$j<=2;$j++)
      {
    if ($i+$j >= count($files)) {
    break;
    }
    $image = $files[$i+$j];
    list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($image);
    $widthn=(int)$width;  
    $heightn=(int)$height;
    if ($widthn < $heightn) {
    $widthn=round($widthn*250/$heightn);
    $heightn=250;
    } else {
    $heightn=round($heightn*250/$widthn);
    $widthn=250;
        }
      echo "<td>" .basename($image) . "<br />"; // show only image name if you want to show full path then use this code // echo $image."<br />";
    echo "<img src='" . $image .  "' height='" . $Heightn . "' width='". $widthn ."'> ";
    echo "</td>";
        }
    echo "</tr>";
    }
    ?>
    </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well the error says it all...you can't divide by zero , so just figure out where "0" it printed out, and fix that most likely is this row $widthn=round($widthn*250/$heightn);

Comment: `$Heightn` is not the same as `$heightn`. You need to fix the capitalization.

Comment: As unexisting variable `$Heightn` is on line 26 (change for  `$heightn`), then it's surely here: `$heightn=round($heightn*250/$widthn);`, your `$width` is null.

Comment: oh. yse. There was also a file in the folder other than the photo which removed this error. But another error persists: Notice: Undefined variable: Heightn in C:\xampp\htdocs\testpic\1.php on line 26

Comment: Just change `$Heightn` to `$heightn` in `echo "<img src='" . $image .  "' height='" . $Heightn . "' width='". $widthn ."'> ";`

Comment: tanks. very very. and idea for group with customer number ...

Comment: Second one  I didn't get the idea - can you give us better example?

Comment: in folder pic my file is 7700251_352_25 (1).jpg and 7700251_352_25 (2).jpg and ... 7700300_371_4112 (1).jpg and 7700300_371_4112 (2).jpg and ... 7722400_520_14 (1).jpg and 7722400_520_14 (2).jpg and ...i want in first row 7700251_352 and under row group pic 7700251_352_* until end. and row next group 7700300_371 and under row group pic 7700300_371_* and ....

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the following code and got the answer I wanted.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<table align="left" border="1" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
<?php
 $groupnum='';
$m=0;

$files = glob("pic/*.*");
for ($i = 0; $i < count($files); $i=$i+3) {
echo "<tr>";
for ($j = 0; $j <= 2; $j++)
  {
if ($m >= count($files)) {
break;
}
$image = $files[$m];
$m++;
list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($image);
$widthn=(int)$width;  
$heightn=(int)$height;
if ($widthn < $heightn) {
$widthn=round($widthn*300/$heightn);
$heightn=300;
} else {
$heightn=round($heightn*300/$widthn);
$widthn=300;
    }
$qroupnumnew=substr(basename($image),0,strpos(basename($image), '_', 8));
    if ($groupnum==$qroupnumnew){



  echo "<td>" .basename($image) . "<br />";
echo "<img src='" . $image .  "' height='" . $heightn . "' width='". $widthn ."'> ";
echo "</td>";
} else {
$groupnum=substr(basename($image),0,strpos(basename($image), '_', 8));
echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td bgcolor='#B4FFA5'> <b>";
echo '<span style="font-size: 30px;">';
            echo $groupnum;
echo "</b></td>";

echo "</tr>";
echo "<tr>";
 echo "<td>" .basename($image) . "<br />"; 
echo "<img src='" . $image .  "' height='" . $heightn . "' width='". $widthn ."'> ";
echo "</td>";
$j=0;
}
    }
echo "</tr>";
}
?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```